# Downloading / Unzipping 20MB takes 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, cordova, zip

I have an app that needs a dictionary type of thing. With images and sounds. There are multiple dictionaries that can be used. Each one when you add up the images + sounds + data is about 20MB a piece.

We decided to ship those separately as single zip files that the user downloads.
The issue is that unzipping 200+ sound files takes FOREVER on these phones. The download takes about 1 min, and unzipping can take up to 10 minutes.

We had an idea to make a sound sprite so it's 1 file, which I believe will help, but does anyone have any other suggestions to help this problem?

This is the unzip code. using the http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.chromium.zip plugin

```
app.util.unzipFile = function(url, destination, progress) {
var fileName = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
var withoutExt = fileName.split('.').shift();
var promise = new $.Deferred();

zip.unzip(url, destination,function(done) {
    if( done === 0) {
        // pass the success callback a file object of the new unzipped thing
        resolveLocalFileSystemURL(destination + "/" + withoutExt, function(unzippedFileEntry) {
            console.log("resolving zip promise");
            promise.resolve(unzippedFileEntry);
        });
    } else {
        app.util.progress.stop();
        promise.reject(err);
        console.log("unzip error", done);
    }
}, progress);

return promise;
};
```

I've tested a bunch of different modern phones, moto x, ssgs4 and 5 and iphone 5s and 5.  When I run the plugin manually via console on the phones I see it unzip faster as a sound sprite file as compared to 200+ sound files. I'm wondering if that is the only way to go here.